# Debug in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, products, admin-panel, magento-2.1.3, debugging

Product update Button is not working in my Magento 2 Store Admin Panel.

[image]

In console of Browser I got below message.

```
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active   
  /new_site/pub/static/version1494750734/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jquery-migrate.js:21
```

I got below message in `var/log/debug.log` file.

```
[2017-05-14 10:31:05] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://mystore.com/new_site/admin_yfpeh1/admin/index/index/key/fdccfbc5eb0a8388bc190aaf17bc1b99237b222767825f7497f230684411cfd5/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BACKEND_MAINMENU"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

`var/log/exception.log` file is empty.

How can I Debug this Situation ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following settings to disable time-stamp in a path like .../static/version1494750734/...:

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings > Sign Static Files > No
```

Or execute the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`path`, `value`) VALUES ("dev/static/sign", 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! You've just saved me hours of work. Losing all my breakpoints every time I refreshed the page was killing me.